# How can I prevent scope creep in my PhD project?

Tags: phd, research-process

I am a senior software engineer with experience in product management (which makes me addicted to proposing new features!). Now, I am an early-career researcher, and I am still looking at my PhD research as a product. This means I keep jumping between ideas and proposals, while the original idea (the big picture) is still the same one I started with. However, even after one year, I am still not clear about the scope. I am unsure about it. Any advice on how to manage this issue?

Comment: I'm in mathematics (at a research-oriented uni in the U.S.), so my experience may not be soooo relevant for you... However, with my PhD students, and in my own projects, it is actually _desirable_, and is inevitable, that with the information acquired along the way, the visible possibilities simply change. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett do you mean it is a feature not a bug (programmer's silly joke:)

Comment: A PhD that plodded along doing exactly what one originally thought would be very boring.

Comment: @AdhamEnaya, haha! Yes, definitely a feature, not a bug. :)

Comment: This seems like a question for your advisor. Set a scope with them and do enough for the degree. You can fly free thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, which is to do "enough" for the degree and move on, let me suggest the following.

Keep a notebook. My preference is a set of notecards, actually that are originally sparse, but which can be revisited. When you get a flash for something that might be added to your project, just make a note of it in the notebook (leaving room for later edits). This is your "future work" cache and can later become the "work in progress" agenda.

Set a scope for the dissertation with the advisor and stick to it (as much as possible/appropriate) and spill the rest into the notebook.

When you finish the degree you have a lot of ideas that might be followed up, which is always a benefit to any academic.

---

It is a good idea to also review the notebook periodically to see if anything might be added without disturbing progress on the main line too much. That is why I like notecards. They can be carried and quickly annotated. Search here for "Hipster PDA" to read more on this idea.